# Laplacian of Lorenz gauge magnetic potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauge-theory, classical-electrodynamics, gauge

My textbook, Gettys's *Physics* (Italian language edition), says that the Lorenz gauge choice uses the magnetic vector potential $$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x},t):=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{y},t-c^{-1}\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|)}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}d^3y $$ which is said to be such that
$$\nabla^2\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x},t)-\varepsilon_0\mu_0\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t^2}=-\mu_0\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t)$$
How is this identity derived?
If $\mathbf{J}$ does not depend on time and is assumed, as often done in physics, to be of class $C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, I know, as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605767/), that $$\nabla^2\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})=-\mu_0\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x}),$$ consistently with the above equation, but I am not able to derive the general case. I heartily thank any answerer.

Comment: It's rather trivial when starting with the Maxwell Equations and writing them in the potential formalism (cf. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Potential_field_approach)). Going your way, I'm not particularly certain about the direction to go, but perhaps knowing the way most physicists would go might help?

Comment: Hi Self-teaching worker. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 4):

So the best way to view this is that you're going to derive $\vec A(\vec x, t)$ from the equations that you want, first and foremost. So we have to start with what equations we want.

## What equations do we want?

The Maxwell equations are:$$\begin{array}{ll}
\nabla\cdot E=\rho/\epsilon_0 & ~~~\nabla \times E = -\dot B\\
\nabla\cdot B = 0 &~~~ \nabla \times B =\mu_0 J + \mu_0\epsilon_0 \dot E
\end{array}$$And our idea is that we see $\nabla\cdot B = 0$ and we know that this means $B = \nabla\times A$ for some $A$. Now looking at $\nabla \times E = -\nabla \times \dot A $ we see that actually $\nabla \times (E + \dot A) = 0$ which means that there must also be a scalar potential $E + \dot A = -\nabla \phi$ for some $\phi$.

Now we ask, "to what extent was that choice of $A, \phi$ free, and to what extent were we constrained?" And the answer is that we have to preserve the fields $E$ and $B$. We know that we preserve $B$ if we add any $\nabla \psi$ to $A$ because the curl of a gradient is zero. But what does that do to our equation for $E$? It gives us $E + \dot A + \nabla \dot\psi = -\nabla \phi.$ Conclusion: we can add any $\nabla \psi$ to $A$ but only if we also subtract $\dot \psi$ to $\phi$, so that we preserve $E$ as well.

This ability to add $\psi$ is called the *gauge freedom* and it is analogous to having a freedom to choose a constant of integration; $A$ and $\phi$ are in some sense integrations of $E$ and $B$.

Now we have two more equations above that we haven't automatically guaranteed by the above construction. Using the identity $\nabla \times (\nabla \times X) = \nabla (\nabla \cdot X) - \nabla^2 X$ we can simplify these considerably.$$
-\nabla^2 \phi - \nabla \cdot \dot A = \rho/\epsilon_0, \\
\nabla (\nabla \cdot A) - \nabla^2 A =\mu_0 J - \mu_0\epsilon_0 \big(\nabla \dot \phi + \ddot A\big).
$$The first thing we see is the emergence of some operator $\Box X = \mu_0\epsilon_0 \ddot X - \nabla^2 X,$ and the next thing is some sort of potential field $\lambda = \nabla \cdot A + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \dot \phi.$ Combining these into the above two equations gives:$$
\Box \phi = \rho/\epsilon_0 + \dot \lambda, \\
\Box A =\mu_0 J - \nabla \lambda.
$$
Okay now remember what I said about the gauge freedom? We can add $\nabla \psi$ to $A$ if we also subtract $\dot\psi$ from $\phi$? What does that do to $\lambda$ as defined above? It changes $\lambda\to\lambda - \Box\psi.$ It turns out that this exactly guarantees that the equations don't change (**Exercise**: prove this, then reflect on why that *has* to be true.)

We can effectively use this to replace $\lambda$ with whatever we want. For example in the Coulomb gauge, we can first imagine that we solve for some arbitrary $\phi(\vec x,~ t)$ and some arbitrary $\vec A(\vec x,~ t),$ so $\lambda(\vec x,~t)$ is some complicated mess. But if we first solve $\Box \psi = \lambda - \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \dot \phi$ the resulting gauge transform maps $\lambda \to \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \dot\phi$ and the above equation becomes $-\nabla^2 \phi = \rho/\epsilon_0,$ solved with the standard Coulomb potential (hence this choice is known as the *Coulomb gauge*). You might object that this creates instantaneous action-at-a-distance, but remember that $E$ is **not** $-\nabla \phi$ in general; it is $-\nabla\phi - \dot A.$ The instantaneous action-at-a-distance in $\phi$ is balanced out by instantaneous action-at-a-distance in $A$ to keep the fields all right.

So the "equations that we want" explicitly contain this no-action-at-a-distance and come when we solve $\Box \psi = \lambda$ to gauge-transform $\lambda\to 0.$
In fact the two equations combine together into a "four-vector" expression: $\Box (\phi/c,~ A) = \mu_0 (c \rho, ~ J).$ And **those** are the equations that we want. (In college it took me a long time to grapple with the question "what happens if the equations of motion take the system to a different $\lambda$?" which turns out to be a pointless question. Recall that we're solving for the fields *at all times*.)

Note that this last step of choosing the gauge basically says "you can always do this," but it doesn't quite construct it for you: our procedure right now is very good for analytical theory but very clumsy for practical theory: "find the fields, guess some $A$, figure out some $\phi$, calculate $\lambda$, solve for the $\psi$ of your dreams, use that to correct $A$ and $\phi$ whose equation no longer will have $\lambda:$ hooray, you're finally in a mathematically pretty place." We want to turn this process around: "take your $\rho, J,$ calculate the right $\phi, A$ in this mathematically pretty place, now use it to get the right $E, B$." Then we become a lean, mean theory machine!

## Now how do we solve these equations?

Okay, we know that in 3D space we could solve expressions of the form $\nabla^2 \alpha = -\beta$ by the solution [you provided](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605767/), $$\alpha(\vec r)  = \frac{1}{4\pi} ~ \int_V d^3 r' ~\frac{\beta(\vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|} = \int d^3 r' ~\eta(\vec r, \vec r').$$ There is a nice way to interpret this in terms of Dirac $\delta$-functions called the "Green's functions" approach; this says that our source equation involves a *linear differential operator* and therefore obeys the principle of superposition, so that if you know its response to a stimulus at any one point, $\beta = \delta_3(\vec r - \vec r')$ is the so-called "Green's function" $\alpha = f(\vec r, \vec r')$, then the actual driver is just a superposition $\beta(\vec r) = \int d^3r' ~\delta_3(\vec r - \vec r') \beta(\vec r'),$ and therefore by linearity the general solution is the weighted superposition of these "Green's functions," $\int d^3r~\beta(\vec r')~f(\vec r, \vec r').$

So the given function $-1/({4\pi|\vec r - \vec r'|})$ is the $\alpha$ you calculate when $\beta(\vec r) = \delta_3(\vec r - \vec r')$ is the 3D Dirac $\delta$-function. You can see this by recognizing the Laplacian as the divergence of a gradient; this describes a field whose divergence is 0 except at one point $\vec r'$ where the divergence suddenly spikes to infinity in such a way so that the surface integral bounding the point is 1. We know that that requires an inverse-square field which goes like $(\vec r - \vec r')/|\vec r - \vec r'|^3$ and we see that that sort of thing would come out as the gradient of $1/|\vec r - \vec r'|,$ and the $4 \pi$ comes from the fact that the surface area of the sphere is naturally $4 \pi r^2$.

So now we come to the idea of $\Box = c^{-2} \partial_t^2 - \nabla^2$ and we want to do the same thing, but we know that $\Box \alpha = 0$ is solved by a superposition of traveling waves, $\alpha(\vec r, t) = \sum_i f_i(\vec r - \vec u_i~t)$ where for all $i$ we know that $|\vec u_i| = c.$ If we imagine a $\delta$-function in space and time, we imagine that it would have to produce a spherical shell propagating in all directions, attenuating as it goes, and so we guess something like $\alpha(\vec r, t) = \delta(t - t' - |\vec r - \vec r'|/c) / (4 \pi |\vec r - \vec r'|).$

This guess turns out to be exactly correct, hence the general solution is the superposition over both coordinates: $$ \alpha(\vec r, t) = \int dt' ~\int d^3 r'~ \delta\left(t - t' - \frac{|\vec r - \vec r'|}c\right)~\frac{\beta(\vec r', t')}{4\pi|\vec r - \vec r'|}.$$Performing the integral over $t'$ you can just use the definition of the $\delta$-function to replace t' with $t - |\vec r - \vec r'|/c$, your expression above.

Alternatively, *just apply $\Box$ to your expression.* This is the "guess and check" method of solving an equation; I've given you the Green's function reason why you should guess this expression as the solution to the equation; now all you have to do is *check* it and if it's correct then it's correct!

For this you're simply doing a divergence of a gradient, where it's useful to know that $\nabla$ obeys the normal product rule for derivatives with $\nabla f\big(|\vec r - \vec r'|\big) = f'\big(|\vec r - \vec r'|\big) ~ (\vec r - \vec r')/|\vec r - \vec r'|.$ We have to say very carefully that $\dot \beta$ is the derivative of $\beta$ with respect to its second argument overall which we'll call $\tau$ for short. So you start with:
$$\nabla \left(\frac{\beta(\vec r', \tau)}{4\pi|\vec r - \vec r'|}\right) = \frac{\vec r - \vec r'}{|\vec r - \vec r'|} \left(\frac{\dot \beta(\vec r', \tau)}{4\pi|\vec r - \vec r'|} - \frac{\beta(\vec r', \tau)}{4\pi|\vec r - \vec r'|^2}\right),$$ and then do the same with the divergence.

Comment: Forgive me for not posting before, but I have not had an Internet connection in these months. I see that you differentiate the integrand, therefore I suppose that you prove the desired identity by diffentiating under the integral sign (which mathematics says that is sometimes possible, sometimes impossible) at least at some step: could you explicitly write them? I heartily thank you again!